# Assigning a different polygon edge colour to the inner edges in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, style

Is it possible in QGIS to assign a different border type to the outer edge of multiple polygons than the inner edges.

This is achievable by dissolving the polygons, which is how I achieved it in the image below, but I would rather assign a style than keep using up storage space by creating the dissolved output.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create your dissolved polygon at the symbology level using the geometry generator with this expression : `buffer( collect(  $geometry ),0)`

[image]

note that the outer edges of the non dissolved polygons are just hidden below the dissolved polygon edge so if you use thinner or transparent outer edge you will see both.